# I want to disable dropdown content on hover(button) but should display the dropdown content on click(button)? Currently i am using bootstrap dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I want to disable dropdown content on hover(button in dropdown) but should display the dropdown content on click(button)? Currently i am using bootstrap dropdown

```
<div class="dropdown" style="margin-left:-104px;">
                        <button
                            class="shape_tool"
                            role="button" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;right:20%">
                            <span class="ui-button-text"><i
                                class="fa fa-folder"></i>File</span>
                        </button>
                          <div class="dropdown-content" style="top:inherit;">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <button onclick="bu.service._saveWorkflow();" class="shape_tool save_publishBtn" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                                        <span class="ui-button-text">Save</span>
                                   </button>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <button onclick="bu.util._showSaveAsDlg();"
                                        class="shape_tool"
                                        role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                                        <span class="ui-button-text">Save As</span>
                                    </button>
                                </a>
```

```
.dropdown-content a{
color: #ffffff;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
```

}

Comment: Please clarify; is this some special Bootstrap plugin? The built-in `dropdown` component for Bootstrap (both v3.x and 4.x) function on `click` already; not `hover`.

Comment: v3.x. I still can't understand whats happening with my dropdown.

Comment: The code you've provided above doesn't look *anything* like Bootstrap's `dropdown` component.  If you're using a plugin that provides extended functionality that could be the problem...  It's also very odd to me to see `<button>` wrapped with an anchor tag.

Comment: css code for dropdown-content    .dropdown-content, .export_menu ,.preferences_menu{
    display: none;
    right: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4a494e;
    min-width: 125px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

Comment: The CSS doesn't impact your question at all.  And the fact remains that *by default* Bootstrap's `dropdown` works as you're asking (on click).  If you're trying to modify a 3rd party dropdown plugin we need to know which one.